# RobotFrameWork: Class name changes how to navigate Robot to 2e TR and 6e TC

Tags: selenium, robotframework

If a class name changes all the time, but a column is always there.

how to navigate RFW to 2nd row and 6 column?
(instead of class name)

https://www.investing.com/equities/pre-market

Comment: With the class name is your table 'id' going to change? 
<table class="genTbl openTbl mostActiveStockTbl crossRatesTbl" **id="premarket_top"** >

Comment: found this: Table Cell Should Contain    xpath=//div[@id='components_block']/table    2    6   2.61

Answer (score 1):

In ROBOT Framework, you can access the element by several ways. See http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html . See section 'Locating elements".

The most common way is by id, name, class, xpath and css_selectors. So, let's assume that it is not possible to get locator by id, name & class due its dynamically changes during page load. So, we will use absolute xpath expressioin for this solution.

In xpath, you can access the node either by i) relative xpath or ii) absolute xpath. 
If the class or id are dynamic and keep changing, then just use it's absolute xpath.

Before that, it is highly recommended if you install an add-on in your web browser for checking/inspecting the xpath element/expression. For firefox, just install 'ChroPath' extension.

The absolute xpath expression below will return a single matching node for ROW=2, COLUMN=6..

```
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/section[1]/div[6]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[6]
```

The absolute xpath expression below will return all matching nodes for all rows, COLUMN=6..

```
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/section[1]/div[6]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr/td[6]
```

Then, in ROBOT Framework, you can access this element like below..

```
${xpath}=   Set Variable   /html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/section[1]/div[6]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[6]
Wait until Page Contains Element   xpath=${xpath}

${output} = Get Text  xpath=${xpath}  #if you want the text of this column.
Click Element   xpath=${xpath} #This will simply click the element
```

Comment: An xpath like this - absolute from the root, following the structure down to the target element - is very unstable; the slightest change in the Page's layout may invalidate it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, if there is slight change in page layout, this absolute xpath need to re-write. There are a few other ways also to access the elements but what I gave above is quite basic for new RF code. However, thanks I will  slightly update my anwser above.